# How to handle errors in express and when to crash immediately to recover from programmer errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was reading through [joyent](https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors)  article about error handling, and I'm totally confused now.
Let's say I have a super simple server:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(a) // a is not defined
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Here  variable `a` is not defined, and when I go to route `/` I get a `ReferenceError`, however, my server continues running. According to joyent:

> A typical example is a REST server (e.g., using restify) where one of the request handlers throws a ReferenceError (e.g., used a mistyped variable name). There are a lot of ways this that continuing on can lead to serious bugs that are extremely difficult to track down.**The best way to recover from programmer errors is to crash immediately**. You should run your programs using a restarter that will automatically restart the program in the event of a crash. With a restarter in place, crashing is the fastest way to restore reliable service in the face of a transient programmer error.

I have a couple of questions now.

1. How do I correctly crash my app immediately if it happens? Do I just `process.exit(1)` in my error handler like this? Is this what I'm supposed to do? :

   ```
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
      if (err.name === 'ReferenceError') {
      process.exit(1)
      } else  {
     // check for other error types and so on...
     }
   })
   ```
2. If my assumption of error handling above is correct, do I handle other errors like `SyntaxError`, `RangeError`, `ReferenceError`, `TypeError`,  `URIError` the same way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, if you want your server to exit, just use `process.exit(someErrorCode)`.  However, `app.use(function (err, req, res, next) { ... }` is for errors while processing a request.  You would generally just send an error status back from the request like `res.sendStatus(500)` if you have no more meaningful error response to send  and log the specific error you got for diagnosis.

Comment: I wouldn't crash my server just because `app.use(function (err, req, res, next) { ...})` got hit.  I'd just send an error response and keep going, but I guess it depends what caused the error.  Crashing and restarting a server can be a meaningful interruption of service for your users.  I would tend to code defensively around meaningful error possibilities to handle them locally.

Comment: @jfriend00 so when do I crash app ? Could you answer this question with details? I think it could help a lot of noobs like myself. Thanks in any case.

Comment: I never crash my server on purpose.  I do have orderly programmatic restarts every once in a while at 4am (when the server is detected as idle) just to clear any possible memory fragmentation or leaking.  I could imagine you might get a persistent error that you don't know how to recover from that could deserve a restart, but you have to be really careful because you don't want to create a crash loop for your server when the real problem is elsewhere (like a database issue).  I'm not writing an answer because I don't agree with your assumptions in the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, I see what you mean. The article states that these types of errors can cause severe issues like: `A connection may be left in an authenticated state and used for a subsequent connection. You may end up running a request for the wrong user.`  It seemed like enough reason for me to restart the app.

Comment: Errors like that are the kind of errors I would catch locally and specifically program a response for.  If all you can do is restart, then `process.exit()` would be the thing to do, but in many cases, you can just shut down the connection so it isn't used again and have code elsewhere that establishes a new connection when needed.  Servers should run for long, long periods of time without restarting and that requires very good and thorough local error handling.

Comment: @jfriend00 so for example in the example provided above, I could just wrap code in route handler in `try catch` and simply just `res.status(500)` in `catch`. And it should be ok in general terms right ? Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Yes, that is an easily catchable error with `try/catch` where you could just send an error status.  Programming errors like that should be caught in unit testing.  That would be perfectly fine and would not cause any type of instabilities.